# Redirect Gradle project dependency on Maven artifact to another Gradle project

Tags: gradle, dependencies, gradle-dependencies

Is there any way to redirect a Gradle project dependency on Maven artifact coordinates to the output of another Gradle project in the same build?

I don’t see the point in having dependencies on things like `project(‘:xyz’)`, since that requires that project `:xyz` be on my file system & built, and for the referencing project to know that `:xyz` is also in the same build. It makes more sense to me to have dependencies on Maven artifact coordinates, and to use artifacts built from projects in the same build that specify matching coordinates, instead of downloading the artifact from a repository.

If this functionality exists, or if I were to make it myself, I’d imagine that it would be implemented as an object that can be listed in the `repositories` closure before all other repositories like  `mavenCentral()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [composite builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). It will allow you to define that a build includes another build and thus Gradle figures out that a dependency notation `group:name:version` gets replaced by an included build.

However I would still recommend using the `project(:xyz)` notation when the projects belong to the same unit, which usually is a single checkout from source control.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish `xyz` in your local repository.

In the project `xyz`, use this plugin :

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

And just run `gradle publishToMavenLocal`

Then, in the "root" project, use in addition the local repository and use `xyz` as a regular dependency :

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile('your.company:xyz:1.0.0')
}
```

Comment: But I’d like to use the source code in my IDE, where I can edit code during debugging, use the same breakpoints in the same source file, only have one tab open for viewing source for a class, etc.

Comment: So the `project(‘:xyz’)` notation is what you need

Comment: I need the functionality that `project(‘:xyz’)` provides, but I shouldn't have to specify dependencies on other projects differently than dependencies on maven artifacts. If I have tons of my own projects that depend on each other, I shouldn't have to include every one in the same build. If my build includes a project that supplies an artifact for the coordinates of a dependency, then Gradle should resolve to that project project. If no project exists in my build, then Gradle should resolve to the next repo in my repositories closure.